# spring data neo4j do not update nodes in a RelationshipEntity

Tags: java, neo4j, spring-data, graph-databases, spring-data-neo4j

I have the following definition of a graph using spring data neo4j.

When I update a Relationship, the changes are propagated to Nodes (@StartNode and @EndNode) of the relationship. How I can avoid this behavior ?

I would only like to update the @RelationshipEntity but not the Nodes of the relationship.

Thanks

```
@Data
public class Graph {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    private String name;

    @Relationship(type = "MADE_OF")
    private List<Relationship> relationships = new ArrayList<>();
}


@Data
@RelationshipEntity(type = "MADE_OF")
public final class Relationship {    
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    @StartNode
    private Node source;

    @EndNode
    private Node target;
}

@Data
public class Node {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;
    private String name;
    private String description;
}
```

Comment: So you update the objects and you don't want them to be persisted if you persist the relationship ?

Comment: I just want to update the existing of the relationship, not the endpoints of the relationship. It is to identify if two objects are related or not, but I do not want to update the endpoints. I do not know if it is possible, I just got started with neo4j.

Comment: In your `public final class Relationship` there is only nodes and id, what are you trying to update in this relationship ?

Answer (score 0):

You can't update a relationship without updating their start and end node if using `session.save(entity)`. Even if you specify a `deph` like `session.save(entity, depth)`.

If the object you are trying to persist is a `RelationshipEntity`, persist it means the start node and the end node will be persisted too. It comes from `org.neo4j.ogm.context.EntityGraphMapper.map(Object, int)` in `neo4j-ogm-core` lib

Think to use `cypher` directly to update your relationship properties.

```
    @Query("MATCH (r) " 
      + " WHERE id(r)={0}"
      + " SET n.yourProperty={1}"
      + " RETURN id(r)")
  public long updateRelationShip(long id, String value);
```